# Using Custom Date Levels(in dimension)

Tags: tableau-api

I have a date column at the date level. I would like to use the date level at the granularity of two weeks (biweekly). Could you please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculation to aggregate the dates at a biweekly level.

In this case I am using a date field called [Date]:

```
IF DATEDIFF('week', DATETRUNC('week', [Date]), #01/01/2015#, 'monday') % 2 = 0 THEN
    DATEADD('week', 2, DATETRUNC('week', [Date])) -1
ELSE
    DATEADD('week', 1, DATETRUNC('week', [Date])) -1
END
```

This calculation checks if a date is an even or odd number of weeks from the reference date (in this case `#01/01/2015#`). I am also defining my weeks as starting on Mondays.

`DATEDIFF(date_part, date1, date2, start_of_week)` returns the difference between date1 and date2 expressed in units of date_part. The start_of_week parameter is optional. If it is omitted, the start of week is determined by the data source.

See more here:

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/functions_functions_date.html